# unit testing with ArgumentValidator.VerifyNotNullOrEmpty

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I am doing unit testing. And I have the following method:

```
  public PortfolioFileGetListDto(string documentsCaseNumber)
        {
            ArgumentValidator.VerifyNotNullOrEmpty(documentsCaseNumber, nameof(documentsCaseNumber));

            CaseNumber = documentsCaseNumber;
        }
```

and I try to unit test this method like so:

```
 [TestMethod]
        public void PortfolioFileGetListDto_Constructor_ShouldValidateParameters()
        {
            // Portfolio           
            Action act = () => new PortfolioFileGetListDto(null);
            act.Should().Throw<ArgumentNullException>().WithMessage("Value cannot be null.\n\rParameter name: portfolio");
        }
```

But if I debug the unit test, I get the following exception:

```
System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: documentsCaseNumber'
```

So how to pass this unit test?

Thank you

Comment: Did you ran the test without debugging it?

Comment: Yes, I did that, but it fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assertions expects message with ".. Parameter name: portfolio", but method under the test will raise exception with parameter name "documentsCaseNumber".

Do you really want to be very strict about the message of the exception?
I would suggest just check that correct name of the variable is included. Type of the exception already confirmed with generic assertion.

```
[TestMethod]
public void Constructor_WithInvalidParameter_ThrowsException()
{     
    Action construct = () => new PortfolioFileGetListDto(null);
    construct.Should().Throw<ArgumentNullException>()
            .Which.Message.Should().ContainEquivalentOf("documentsCaseNumber");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The assertion depends on which Unit-Test-Framework you are using.

For Microsoft TestPlatform:

```
var exception = Assert.ThrowsException<Exception>(x => {
    new PortfolioFileGetListDto(null);
});
Assert.AreEqual("Value cannot be null.\n\rParameter name: portfolio", exception.Message);
```

Comment: Thank you. But I have that isn' t. But then with act.should(). Or not?

Comment: And Assert doesn't have a ThrowsException